# ajax(xmlhttprequest)to string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am making an ajax call using webservice url, which gives me data. basicaly that url in browser looks like xml as it is xmlhttprequest. I am able to print the data when there is only set of entry for e.g. for single entry its working:

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each):

```
$xml.find("Coupon").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).find("CouponID").text(),
        rewardItem = $(this).find("RewardItem").text();

    alert(id);
    alert(rewardItem);
});
```

Basically, it's iterating over each `Coupon` element and finding the `CouponID` and `RewardItem` elements inside.

Comment: Thanks, I can alert output works great. but how about displaying each id and reward item separately? I mean different buttons will be generated based on the number of result and each button will show you ID and reward item on different page. Thanks for your help. God bless u

Comment: basicaly wanna generate buttons in mobile based on reward item name

Comment: $('<button type="submit"  data-theme="b" id="btnCheckCoupon" cid="' + $(this).find('CouponID').text() + '">' + $(this).find('RewardItem').text() + '</button><br>').appendTo('#rewarditemlist'); is aactaly printing different button name based on rewarditem, but how to get details of each id and reward item when click on respective button?

Comment: #rewarditemlist is declared empty initialy

Comment: @Katrina peterson: You could use `data-*` attributes to store the information you need and then retrieve it on click.